# Bayes Theorem in Probability

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A harmful particle test for houses is correct 2/3 of the time if the particles are present, and correct
4/5 of the time if the particles are absent. The proportion of houses with harmful particles is 1/6. If
a random house is tested and the test comes out negative, what is the probability the particles are
absent?

A -> Particle is absent
B -> Test is negative

P(A|B) = ?

I get P(B'|A') = 2/3 , --> P(B|A) = 1 - 2/3 = 1/3, P(B'|A) = 4/5 , P(A') = 1/6

The answer is 12/13. I don't understand where my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In order to semplify the calculation I set $\frac{1}{6}=\frac{3}{18}$

$\mathbb{P}[ A \cap B]=\frac{4}{5}\frac{15}{18}=\frac{12}{18}$

$\mathbb{P}[B]=\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{18}+\frac{4}{5}\frac{15}{18}=\frac{13}{18}$

doing the ratio you get the solution: $\mathbb{P}[A|B]=\frac{12}{13}$

**Further Explanation:**

$\mathbb{P}[ A \cap B]$ is the probability to get "Negative Test AND No Harmful Particle" (it is a correct test!)

$\mathbb{P}[B]$ is the probability to get a Negative Test: we have 2 cases to be summed

- Negative Test AND Harmful Particle (incorret test)
- Negative Test AND No Harmful Particle (correct test)

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: @EmmaVaze :  Just edited my answer: I hope now it is clear :)

Comment: But 4/5 is for negative test when no particle is present. Isn't it P(B'/A)?

Comment: @EmmaVaze : exatcly what i did. $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{5}{6}=\frac{2}{3}=\frac{12}{18}$ as I showed to semplify the calculations with fractions